# Creating divs in code behind with strange layout?

Tags: c#, for-loop, alternating

I have a for loop which loops over a number of images and displays them as part of a user control in a web project.

I need to be able to display two images in a div and then 1 image and then two images etc..

I have the following code which puts two images in a div but havent managed to find out how to alternate between 1 and 2?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbMain = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < FADS.Count; i++)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    sb.Append("<div class=\"featrow\">");

    FeatAdv fad = FADS[i];
    sb.AppendFormat("<a href=\"{0}\" target='BannerPage' title=\"{1}\">", params);
    sb.AppendFormat("<img src='{0}'/></a>", ImagePath.FromLocal(imagelocation));

    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        sb.Append("</div>");
        sbMain.Append(sb);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing very little of your code.

At the moment you are opening a `div` before every even-numbered image

```
if(i % 2 == 0)
    sb.Append("<div class=\"featrow\">");
```

and closing after every odd-numbered image

```
if (i % 2 != 0) // equivalently i % 2 == 1
{
    sb.Append("</div>");
    sbMain.Append(sb);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

If you wanted the images in simple groups of three, you could replace the conditions with

```
if (i % 3 == 0)
```

and

```
if (i % 3 == 2)
```

respectively.

But you *also* want to open a `div` before the *third* element and close one after the *second* element, so you can replace the conditions with

```
if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 3 == 2))
```

and

```
if ((i % 3 == 1) || (i % 3 == 2))
```

respectively.

Note that, as with your original code, you need to check after the loop to make sure you haven't opened a `div` and fialed to close it - this will happen if you have a number of images one more than a multiple of three. (One more than a multiple of two, in your original code.)

Comment: How would you check that the div has been closed?

Comment: @user3529183 (Edit, much simpler) Check if `FADS.Count % 3 == 1`.

Comment: That's great cheers. After the loop I have checked that FADS.Count % 3 == 1 nad if it does I have appended another closing div to the stringbuilder and also appended that string tot he sbMain string builder. That should work right?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to loop through you array selecting 3 elements at a time. I've written this but can't test as I don't have all your data :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbMain = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < FADS.Count; i+=3)
{
    sb.Append("<div class=\"featrow\">");


    for(int j =i ; j<=i+2 ;j++){

        if(j < FADS.Count){

            if(j==i+2){
                sb.Append("</div>");
                sb.Append("<div class=\"featrow\">");
            }
            FeatAdv fad = FADS[j];
            sb.AppendFormat("<a href=\"{0}\" target='BannerPage' title=\"{1}\">", params);
            sb.AppendFormat("<img src='{0}'/></a>", ImagePath.FromLocal(imagelocation));

            if(j==i+2){
                sb.Append("</div>");
            }
        }
    }

    sbMain.Append(sb);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Comment: Would love to be able to use this method but FADS is a list and so doesn't contain a method for length?

Comment: Ok in that case replace length by size()

Comment: @user3529183 : did you checked my answer?

Answer (score -3):

This one is in jQuery,but can help you:

```
<div class="test"></div>
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=10;
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++) {
    var html='<div class="inner">';
        html +='<a href="#">Image 1</a>'
        if(i%2==0) {
           html +='<a href="#">Image 2</a>'
        }
        html +="</div>";
        $('.test').append(html);
    }

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bFL88/1/)

Comment: We are talking in Java here, bad answer

Comment: Well I thought we are talking about for loop as well

Comment: c# my mitake but almost the same in the syntax

Comment: I think for loop is kind of same in javascript or jQuery or in C#,so I answered,but people want full working code from here,not the hint.

Comment: Yes that's why you got downvoted. If it was a hint ,just use comments

Comment: Good suggestion,I'm just trying to help.